# compilation error in creating Javascript's object from Angular Form Controls

Tags: angular

My model is

```
export class User {
  firstname:string = '';
  lastname:string = '';
  email:string = '';

  constructor(values:Object={}){
    Object.assign((this,values));
  }
```

}

I have an sign-up form created in Angular

```
 signupForm:FormGroup;

  constructor(private userManagementService: UserManagementService, private fb:FormBuilder) {
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm(){
    this.signupForm = this.fb.group({
      firstName:['',Validators.required], 
      lastName:['',Validators.required],
      email:['',Validators.required],
      password:['',Validators.required]
    });
  }

  addUser(){
    this.newUser = new User({
      this.signUpForm.get('firstName').value,
      this.signUpForm.get('lastName').value,
      this.signUpForm.get('email').value
    });
    console.log("in SignupComponentComponent: addUser: "+this.newUser);
    this.userManagementService.addUser(this.newUser);
  }
```

I'll call addUser from HTML button

```
<button type="button" (click)="addUser()"id="signup-button" class="content-div__button--blue"> Sign Up! </button>
```

The problem is I am getting compilation error `error TS1005: ':' expected` for the following lines in addUser

```
  this.signUpForm.get('firstName').value,
  this.signUpForm.get('lastName').value,
  this.signUpForm.get('email').value
```

Comment: Copied from an online tutorial. Didnt really notice. Do you see an issue?

Comment: @JD - Interesting you pointed out `constructor(values:Object={}){
Object.assign((this,values));}`. I had to remove the extra braces as I was getting empty values with it. Changed to `constructor(values:Object={}){
    Object.assign(this,values);}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code snippet.

```
addUser(){
    this.newUser = new User({
      firstname: this.signupForm.get('firstName').value,
      lastname:this.signupForm.get('lastName').value,
      email:this.signupForm.get('email').value
    });
```

Comment: Many thanks Santosh, J.D, your answers are same. It worked.